# How to parse a sequence of integers stored in a text buffer?

Tags: c++

Parsing text consisting of a sequence of integers from a stream in C++ is easy enough: just decode them. When the data is received somehow and is readily available within a program, e.g., receiving a base64 encoded text (the decoding isn't the problem), the situation is a bit different. The data is sitting in a buffer within the program and only needs to be decoded, not read. Of course, a `std::istringstream` could be used:

```
std::vector<int> parse_text(char* begin, char* end) {
    std::istringstream in(std::string(begin, end));
    return std::vector<int>(std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
                            std::istream_iterator<int>());
}
```

Since a lot of these buffers are received and they can be fairly big, it is desirable to *not* copy the actual content of character array and, ideally, to also avoid creating a stream for each buffer. Thus, the question becomes:

Given a buffer of `char`s containing a sequences of (space separated; dealing with other separators is easily done, e.g., using a suitable manipulator) integers how can they be decoded without copying the sequence and, if possible, without creating even an `std::istream`?

Comment: I'd suggest http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol except I believe you're asking this in order to answer it properly yourself. After all you implemented pretty efficient iostreams. ;-) So, only suggesting that you add a statement at beginning about how you ask this in order to answer it (and elicit other possible answers, comments etc.), perhaps with link to the relevant part of SO guidelines (it's there).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf _'After all you implemented pretty efficient iostreams.'_ Yeah, that's where I met the OP first (decades ago ;-D ) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: i didn't quite get the nick thing, but then i lack a classical education. just a humble engineer. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The _nick thing_ is primarily about the fancy greek characters (it really caught up a number of nasty people). The philosophical background about the meaning of the nick is fairly simple, and evidents with age (so even c++ changed the standards after years of patient indulgence ;-) ). I'm just a humble engineer also ...

Comment: @Thomas: Actually, you'll find that there are significantly different considerations for parsing integers from arbitrary numbers.  For example, the tradeoff between precision and speed.

Comment: I hope an answer to this, when it comes, considers dependencies (where `strtol` wins by a mile, since it's in the Standard Library), reuse of existing libraries (Boost::Spirit::Qi would be a good choice), efficiency, support for a variety of input formats, such as thousands separators, localization (the normal ASCII digits, Arabic numerals, Roman numerals), etc

Comment: @BenVoigt: Arabiic or Roman numerals are interesting and not quite as readily supported by the approach posted: you'll need to set up the global `std::locale` with a suitable `std::num_get<char, char const*>` facet. Since the standard C++ library doesn't ship with a corresponding fact it is hard to predict whether a custom facet can be instantiated for the correct parameters. Other than that, I think the answer posted offers the flexibility asked for although possibly not at the speed of `strtol()`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: πάντα ῥεῖ isn't that hard to decode: "panta rei" - these are all typicaly math symobls (pi, alpha, ny, tau, alpha, rho, epsilon, iota). ... and that in turn is used to describe one of the central statements of [Heraclitus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus): "Everything flows".

Comment: @DietmarKühl: thanks. heracles seems pretty modern, even in advance of modern cosmology (which i tend to confuse with astrology, it's much the same, isn't it? :-)). "everything flows" = "the universe is a process", and "this world, which is the same for all, no one of gods or men has made; but it always was and will be: an ever-living fire, with measures of it kindling, and measures going out" = "the universe was not made / had no creation, it's eternal; stuff is created and stuff is destroyed" = steady state hypothesis. hm. and math symbols to boot.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Heraclitus, not Heracles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoiding a copy of the buffer is easily done with a custom stream buffer which simply sets of the get area to use the buffer. The stream buffer actually doesn't even need to override any of the virtual functions and would just set up the internal buffer:

```
class imemstream
    : private virtual std::streambuf
    , public std::istream
{
public:
    imemstream(char* begin, char* end)
        : std::streambuf()
        , std::istream(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this))
    {
        this->setg(begin, begin, end); 
    }
};

std::vector<int> parse_data_via_istream(char* begin, char* end)
{
    imemstream in(begin, end);
    return std::vector<int>(std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
                            std::istream_iterator<int>());
}
```

This approach avoids copying the stream and uses the ready made `std::istream` functionality. However, it does create a stream object. With a suitable update function the stream stream/stream buffer can be extended to reset the buffer and process multiple buffers.

To avoid creation of the stream, the underlying functionality from `std::num_get<...>` could be used. The actual parsing is done by one of the `std::locale` facets. The numeric parsing for `std::istream` is done by `std::num_get<char, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>>`. This facet isn't much help as it uses  a sequence specified by `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`s but a `std::num_get<char, char const*>` facet can be instantiated. It won't be in part of the default `std::locale` but it easy to create a corresponding `std::locale` and install it, e.g., as the global `std::locale` object first thing in `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale(std::locale(),
                                    new std::num_get<char, char const*>()));
    ...
```

Note that the `std::locale` object will clean-up the added facet, i.e., there is no need to add any clean-up code: the facets are reference counted and released when the last `std::locale` holding a particular facet disappears. To actually use the facet it, unfortunately, needs an `std::ios_base` object which is can only really be obtained from some stream object. However, any stream can be used (although in a multi-threaded system it should probably be a separate stream object per stream to avoid accidental race conditions):

```
char const* skipspace(char const* it, char const* end)
{
    return std::find_if(it, end,
                        [](unsigned char c){ return !std::isspace(c); });
}

std::vector<int> parse_data_via_istream(std::ios_base& fmt,
                                        char const* it, char const* end)
{
    std::vector<int> rc;
    std::num_get<char, char const*> const& ng
        = std::use_facet<std::num_get<char, char const*>>(std::locale());

    std::ios_base::iostate error;
    for (long tmp;
         (it = ng.get(skipspace(it, end), end, fmt, error, tmp))
             , error == std::ios_base::goodbit; ) {
        rc.push_back(tmp);
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Most of this just about a bit of error handling and skipping leading whitespace: mostly, `std::istream` provides facilities to automatically skip whitespace for formatted input and deals with the necessary error protocol. There is potentially a small advantage of the approach outlined above with respect to getting the facet just once per buffer and avoiding creation of a `std::istream::sentry` object as well as avoiding creation of a stream. Of course, the code assumes that some stream can be used to pass it in as its `std::ios_base&` subobject to provide parsing flags like the base to be used.

OK, this is quite a bit of code for something which `strtol()` could mostly do, too. The approach using `std::num_get<char, char const*>` has some flexibility which isn't offered by `strtol()`:

1. Since the `std::locale`'s facet are used which can be overridden to parse arbitrary formats of representation, e.g., Roman numerals, it more flexible with respect to input formats.
2. It is easy to set up use of thousands separators or change the representation of the decimal point (just change `std::numpunct<char>` in `std::locale` used by `fmt` to set these up).
3. The buffer doesn't have to be null-terminated. For example, a contiguous sequence of character made up of 8 digit values can be parsed by feeding `it` and `it+8` as the range when calling `std::num_get<char, char const*>::get()`.

However, `strtol()` is probably a good approach for most uses. On the other hand, the above provides an alternative which may be useful in some contexts.

Comment: To qualify as zero-copy, one ought to reserve the vector based on the size of the input?  Additionally, this seems like a lot of code compared to a simple loop with `std::strtol` and vector `push_back`, which would also work in C++98.  Mind explaining the advantages?

Comment: @BenVoigt: How do I set up `strtol()` to deal with thousand separators? ... or Arabic/Roman numerals? Admittedly, on reason for the question and answer is that I got asked about how to use `std::num_get<char, ...>` in an e-mail and I prefer to write answers potentially useful to others in a public location :-)

Comment: Of course there's a tradeoff between support for multiple input formats, speed, simplicity, and low footprint.  I'm not as familiar as you are with what formatting would be accepted by `num_get()` and not `strtol()`, which is why I asked what the advantages are.

Comment: Why are you using the global locale and not the locale from `fmt`?

Comment: I like how I program C++ for a living and I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Also, the buffer isn't necessarily null-terminated and the text an be embedded within other text, i.e., just changing a byte may not be an option or the buffer may be immutable in the first place (e.g. because it is read-only memory mapped block). With respect to the supported format, assuming the global `std::locale` object is set up properly, any format can be used: you can inherit from `std::num_get<...>` and override the respective `do_get()` format.

Comment: @NeilKirk You can get a book on IOStreams and probably look at some source code. It's not too hard when you understand what's going on.

Comment: @0x499602D2: actually, the use of the `std::locale()` instead of `fmt.getloc()` is an artifact of how I tested the code: I just passed on of the standard stream objects and these were created before the global `std::locale` object was modified, i.e., they don't include the required `std::num_get<char, char const*>` facet. I guess, a real implementation would actually use `fmt.getloc()`.

Comment: @NeilKirk: well, there is flexibility you _can_ use if you need to. Obviously, most often it is hopefully not necessary. I agree that hardly anybody knows about these facilities, though.